# Authentication in Office addin using ADAL and Dialog API

Tags: office-js, adal, office-addins, adal.js, office-web-app

Unable to authenticate Office add-in using Dialog API and ADAL.

I am trying to authenticate a user using Dialog API and ADAL. The Dialog is opening fine, but I am receiving error that the reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application. The reply url is configured as the dialog URL both in the code as well as in App Registration.

```
        $("#btnSignin").click(function () {
            var url = "https://localhost:44367/auth.html";
            Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { height: 40, width: 40 }, function (result) {
                _dlg = result.value;
                _dlg.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, dialogMessageReceived);
            });
        });
```

The URL - https://localhost:44367/auth.html is configured as the redirectUri and while debugging also authcontext.config.redirectUri points to https://localhost:44367/auth.html?_host_Info=Excel$Win32$16.01$en-US$telemetry$isDialog".

I am not sure why it is giving the error, though the urls are configured correctly.Is there anyother redirectUri to be added ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit to complicated to put in a comment, so I'll use an "answer" for now.

Where are you seeing the error? In a JavaScript console? In a popup?

Please open the raw manifest of the app registration in the Azure portal and see what is the value of the `replyUrlsWithType` property.

Please use the Fiddler tool to see the HTTP Request that is going to the login URL:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{YOUR O365 TENANCY GUID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope={VARIOUS SCOPES}&response_type=code&client_id={YOUR APP'S REGISTRATION ID IN AAD}&redirect_uri={YOUR LOCALHOST REDIRECT URL}`

What is the exact string that is being sent as the `redirect_uri`? It will be URL-encoded, but otherwise it should match what's in the raw manifest.

Comment: Hi Rick, Thank you for your reply. The raw manifest contains the url as https://localhost:44367/auth.html and type="web". And also in the fiddler trace the redirect uri is https://localhost:44367/auth.html. Encoded URL (redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44367%2fauth.html) But still I am getting the same error. The error is occurring in the Pop-up.

Comment: @AhmedVali Try running the add-in and then navigating directly to https://localhost:44367/auth.html in a browser. You'll get an error in that Office.js is loaded outside the Office client, but I'd like to see if you get any other errors and if the login page opens.

Comment: Hi Rick, I don't see any other error. I could only see the Warning that Office.js is loaded outside of Office client.

Comment: @AhmedVali Does the error message give the GUID of the application? If so, does it match the registered app ID of your add-in? If not, what is the GUID?

Comment: Hi Rick, Does it have to do anything with granting access_tokens permissions in Azure Portal ? I have only enabled id_tokens earlier. But now after enabling access_tokens as well, the authentication is working fine.But I have no idea why the error was showing as reply url incorrect ?